# How to calculate Total Number of Days by reading the Date mentioned in a text file till today?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell, data-science

I have a text file which contains few data as follows .

---

### 2018-07-20

### 2018-08-13

### 2018-07-30

### 2018-07-18

### 2018-07-24

### 2018-08-13

### 2018-07-20

2018-08-10

I need to find the number of days from the mentioned dates till today , This python or shell script will take input the file as follows f = open("/root/interview/date1.txt", "r").read().split("\n")  & calculate with system time .
The expected Output can be something like **300 Days** difference .
I am not good with python or shell script .Can someone please help .

Comment: Make sure to include your expected output in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```py
import datetime


dates = []

# Reading dates from dates.txt and
# removing all spaces in the head and tail of the string
with open('dates.txt', 'r') as f:
    dates = [i.strip() for i in f.readlines()]

# now dates list contains a bunch of strings like "2018-07-24"

today = datetime.datetime.now().date()

for date_str in dates:
    year, month, day = list(map(int, date_str.split('-')))
    # year, month and day are now integers
    # year = 2018
    # month = 7
    # day = 24

    date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    days_passed = (today - date).days
    print(f'{days_passed} days passed since {date_str}')
```

And the output is:

```
641 days passed since 2018-07-20
617 days passed since 2018-08-13
631 days passed since 2018-07-30
643 days passed since 2018-07-18
637 days passed since 2018-07-24
617 days passed since 2018-08-13
641 days passed since 2018-07-20
620 days passed since 2018-08-10
```

It uses `datetime` module, which has all the functions for working with date and time.